# How can I run through all these ifs in python?

Tags: json, python-3.x, if-statement

When I run the program It will only run the first If and make those specific changes. Noticed when i switched them around and only the first one gives me what I want... Thanks for the help.

```
    if SW1 != r['SW1']: #check the received value of SW1 & change it on the App if there is a mismatch
        print("Changing SW1 status to the value in the database.")
        if self.sw1.active == True:
            self.sw1.active = False
        else:
            self.sw1.active = True
    else:
        return

    if LED1 != r['LED1']: #check the received value of led1 & change it on the App if there is a mismatch
        print("Changing LED1 status to the value in the database.")
        if self.led1.active == True:
            self.led1.active = False
        else:
            self.led1.active = True
    else:
        return
    
    if LED2 != r['LED2']: #check the received value of led2 & change it on the App if there is a mismatch
        print("Changing LED2 status to the value in the database.")
        if self.led2.active == True:
            self.led2.active = False
        else:
            self.led2.active = True
        
    else:
        
    
    if LED3 != r['LED3']: #check the received value of led3 & change it on the App if there is a mismatch
        print("Changing LED3 status to the value in the database.")
        if self.led3.active == True:
            self.led3.active = False
        else:
            self.led3.active = True
    else:
        return
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @Mendelg sorry, wasn't allowed to post a snippet. Just added the code. Thanks.

Comment: what do you expect to happen when you put `return` in the `else` clause? are you sure you want the function to short-circuit after just one of them fails?

Comment: If condition will always check for TRUE if it is then it will not execute else statements. However if you want to check multiple statements to be TRUE, use multiple 'if'.

Comment: Please specify in which part you want to check multiple statements to be TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

You should not `return` in `else` after every `if`. This will make the function to close after the first `if` is failed. I will explain it further with one example.

Take this function which checks if a number is even.

```
def foo_bar(n):
    if n%2==0:
        print("Even")
    else:
        return

    print("I have been reached")
```

If an even number is passed, you will see the below output

```
>>> foo_bar(10)
Even
I have been reached
```

If the Odd number is passed, you will not see any output as the function is returning None and Terminated in `else`.

Now if you have multiple `if`s in the function,

```
def foo_bar(n):
    if n%2==0:
        print("Even")
    else:
        return
    if n%3==0:
        print("Divisible by 3")
    

    print("I have been reached")
```

If you pass `9` as an argument, the above function prints nothing. It is because after one condition is checked , you are returning `None` which terminates the function.

Hope this answers your question.